# How to enable compression for Flink broadcast state checkpoints

Tags: flink-streaming

I'm using Flink 1.14.4, and have an issue with very large checkpoints for broadcast state. The [Flink docs](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/ops/state/large_state_tuning/#compression) say:

> Flink offers optional compression (default: off) for all checkpoints and savepoints

However this setting doesn't seem to be used for broadcast state. I see the `keyGroupCompressionDecorator` being used by `HeapKeyedStateBackend`, but not by `HeapBroadcastState`. I also tested w/turning on compression, and it didn't change the size of broadcast state.

Did I miss something, or is this an intentional restriction, or just a miss in the code?

Answer (score 1):

`BroadcastState` is an operator state not a `KeyedState`. The referenced docs refer to a `KeyedState`:

> Compression works on the granularity of key-groups in keyed state,

Probably docs could be more explicit about this behaviour.

Unfortunately as far as I know there is no compression for OperatorState. I am not 100% sure, but I believe it's just has never been implemented, because we did not want to invest in it, as `KeyedState` should be preferred in majority of cases.

Comment: Note that as of Flink 1.18, operator state (and thus broadcast state) is compressed. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-30113